# How can i add File transfer to a group chat?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, serversocket

I have a java code for group chat. I want to send file to all clients connected to server. If I am using a `PrintWriter` for chatting mechanism, will I need any other things like `OutputStream` for file transfer? Is there any other method for transferring files? Can we use both of them?

Comment: Additional information is needed.  Do you have some kind of service running on the server side?  If it is a rest service, can you Base64 encode the file and send it to the server?  Are you using Sockets for your program?

Comment: @Ali -Yes I am using sockets in my program.Server is multithreaded and creates a thread for each client. I get the OutputStream from here: public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, PrintWriter user) 
 {
sock = clientSocket;
InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
 reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
cOutputStreams.add(os);
Even when I use OutputStream to transfer a .pdf file from server, I am having problems as only 0KB file arrives at client side.

Comment: I personally would not use InputStream/OutputStream in a group chat application.  You would need something to specify which file is being sent, its type, and who its recipient(s) should be.  A rest service should be created that handles sending and receiving messages.  You will not need to worry about if a Reader/Writer or InputStream/OutputStream should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The Reader/Writer classes are used with character.  The InputStream/OutputStream are used with bytes.  Depending upon the type of the file, you will need to use either a Writer or an OutputStream.  If you are receiving and sending text files, use Reader/Writer; If you are receiving and sending images, zip files, pdfs (binary files) use InputStream/OutputStream.

Check the classes under the java.io package for different types of Reader/Writer and InputStream/OutputStream to see which is suitable for your needs.

Comment: -If i am to use both of them is it possible? Do i need to close one to use other?